# django access answers to math tasks in different view

Tags: django

I want to write a website that gives elementary math tasks to its visitors, quite similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/r4QTQ/

In contrast to the JS example my idea is for the visitor to finish all tasks first, then press a button "check answers" and have all answers marked with a smiley if answer is right or the correct result if visitor's answer is wrong. To this - if I'm right - it's necessary to redirect the visitor's answers and the task-list to a different view. Also I want to use Django templates and CBviews.

I have this view for setting up the math tasks - view.py:

```
class Plus_im_10erPageView(TemplateView):
    form_class = AnswerForm
    template_name = 'plus_im_10er.html'
    success_html = 'plus_im_10er_check.html'

    def tasks(self):
        # make a list of math tasks here
        return task_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Plus_im_10erPageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        task_list = self.tasks()
        context['tasks'] = task_list
        self.context = context

        return context

    def post(self, request):
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            answers = form.cleaned_data
            print(answers)
        return render(request, self.success_html, {'answers': answers}
```

The AnswerForm is a collection of 10 CharFields like this - forms.py:

```
class AnswerForm(forms.Form):
    answer_1 = forms.CharField(label='answer', required=False)
    answer_2 = forms.CharField(label='answer', ...
    ...
```

Next is the template - plus_im_10er.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<ul>
    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for task in tasks %}
        <li>{{ task.0 }} + {{ task.1 }} = 
            <input type="text" size=2 name="answer_list"
                   onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <=57">{{ answer }}
            </input>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type="button" onclick="location.href='/plus_im_10er_check/';"
           value="Check answers">
    </input>
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

This works so far.

What I cannot figure out is how to continue. My idea is to write a second view called Plus_im_10er_checkPageView and a second template called plus_im_10er_check.html but whatever I tried didn't get me anywhere. I spare you my attempts. How would you tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution. It's not pretty, so I would appreciate ideas to refacture it.

Starting with view.py:

```
class Plus_im_10erPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'plus_im_10er.html'
    success_html = 'plus_im_10er_check.html'
    no_of_tasks = 3

    @classmethod
    def generate_plus10_tasks(self):
        """
        Generate tasks containing two addends with a sum less or equal 10.
        """
        task_list = []
        for _ in range(self.no_of_tasks):
            while True:
                x = random.randint(0, 9)
                y = random.randint(0, 9)
                result = x + y
                if result <= 10:
                    task_list.append((x, y, result))
                    break
        self.task_list = task_list
        return task_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)  # noqa
        context['task_list'] = self.generate_plus10_tasks()
        self.context = context
        return context

    def post(self, request):
        form = AnswerForm(request.POST)
        answered_tasks = []

        if form.is_valid():
            answers = form.cleaned_data
            total_correct_answers = 0

            # helper to get the form_field name
            index = 1

            for task in self.task_list:
                if index > self.no_of_tasks:
                    break
                answer = int(answers[f'answer_{index}'])
                x, y, correct_result = task
                if answer == correct_result:
                    total_correct_answers += 1
                answered_tasks.append((x, y, correct_result, answer,
                                       total_correct_answers))  # noqa
                index += 1

        return render(request,
                      self.success_html,
                      {'answered_tasks': answered_tasks}
                      )
```

The forms:

```
from django import forms

class AnswerForm(forms.Form):
    answer_1 = forms.CharField(label='answer', required=False)
    answer_2 = forms.CharField(label='answer', required=False)
    answer_3 = forms.CharField(label='answer', required=False)
    answer_4 = forms.CharField(label='answer', required=False)
    answer_5 = forms.CharField(label='answer', required=False)
    answer_6 = forms.CharField(label='answer', required=False)
    answer_7 = forms.CharField(label='answer', required=False)
    answer_8 = forms.CharField(label='answer', required=False)
    answer_9 = forms.CharField(label='answer', required=False)
    answer_10 = forms.CharField(label='answer', required=False)
```

plus_im_10er.html

```
<!-- templates/plus_im_10er.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Plus rechnen im 10er-Raum</h2>
<ul>
    <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for task in task_list %}
        <li><label for="id_answer">{{ task.0 }} + {{ task.1 }} = </label>
            <input id="id_answer" type="text" size=2 name="answer_{{ forloop.counter }}"
                   onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <=57">{{ form }}
            </input>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
    </br></br>
    <form action="/plus_im_10er_check/" method="GET">
        <input type="submit" value="Antworten prüfen">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

plus_im_10er_check.html

```
<!-- templates/plus_im_10er_check.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Plus rechnen im 10er-Raum</h2>
<h3>Antworten prüfen</h3>
<ul>
    <div>
        {% for task in answered_tasks %}
            {% if task.2 == task.3 %}
                <li>{{ task.0 }} + {{ task.1 }} = {{ task.3 }} &#128515</li>
            {% else %}
                <li>{{ task.0 }} + {{ task.1 }} &#8800 {{ task.3 }}</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </br>
    Du hast {{ answered_tasks.2.4 }} &#128515 von 3.
    </div>
    </br></br>
  <a href="/plus_im_10er/"><button type="button">Neue Aufgaben</button></a>
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

Ande the result looks like this:

[image: Giving three math tasks to pupil]

[image: Giving results]